# How to reopen Doctrine Entity Manager after DBALException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a console application with Symfony 2, the script run on cron (terminal). But, after \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException the script throw N \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException with message "The EntityManager is closed.".

This is partial of script:

```
try {

    $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    // ...

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = new Post();
    $entity
        ->setAuthor($author)
        ->setTitle($title)
        ->setContent($content)
    ;

    $manager->persist($entity);
    $manager->flush();

    $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->commit();

    return $entity->getId();

} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {

    $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();

    $output->writeln(sprintf(
        '<error>[!] %s (%s) the post could not be created "%s"</error>',
        get_class($e),
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        $e->getMessage()
    ));

    return false;

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->rollback();

    $output->writeln(sprintf(
        '<error>[!] %s (%s) the post could not be created "%s"</error>',
        get_class($e),
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        $e->getMessage()
    ));

    return false;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you see this question and answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14261250/2779152

Comment: Yes i did before open this thread.

Answer (score 16):

You can reset your entity manager manualy like this :

```
//...
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if (!$manager->isOpen()) {
        $manager = $manager->create(
            $manager->getConnection(),
            $manager->getConfiguration()
        );
    }

    $output->writeln(sprintf(
        '<error>[!] %s (%s) the post could not be created "%s"</error>',
        get_class($e),
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        $e->getMessage()
    ));

    return false;
} 
//...
```

Comment: There might be issues even after resetting the Entity Manager - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5339

Comment: That it not working for me.. This is a bug of Symfony or Doctrine?

Comment: Some of these methods are not available in newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

On Symfony 5 I reopened connection in this way:

```
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Exception $e) {
     /** @var \Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry */
     $managerRegistry->resetManager();
}
```

I have seen other cases where they use return value of `resetManager(): ObjectManager` as new entity manager instead of continuing using the same entity manager. But it is unnecessary, you can continue using the same entity manager.

Comment: it turns out to be necessary. they tend to remove things, like `em->refresh` i.o. adding them. I have a usecase for this: foreign component I cannot modify has memory leaks and manager reset saved my day.

Comment: @Galvani if you mean memory leaks described here https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8891 then you can apply suggestions described there

Answer (score -3):

If you use PSR-15 and PHP-DI in your project, try this middleware:

https://github.com/autorusltd/doctrine-persistent-entity-manager-middleware

You can use it like this:

```
use Arus\Middleware\DoctrinePersistentEntityManagerMiddleware;

$requestHandler->add(new DoctrinePersistentEntityManagerMiddleware($container));

$requestHandler->handle($request);
```

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of this middleware is and how it works?