# Persist from Kernel Listener throw EntityManager is closed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to persist a Log entity (ip,url,path,user,date...) everytime a URL is requested or served. I'm getting the "EntityManager is closed" error.
I'm looking for a simple solution if possible.
My code is the following:

First the YAML 
    services:

```
kernelListener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\KernelListener
    arguments: [ '@my_logger']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: onKernelTerminate }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }

my_logger:
    class:        AppBundle\Service\Logger
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@security.token_storage' ]
    scope: prototype
```

Here it's my Logger service:

```
 namespace AppBundle\Service;
use AppBundle\Entity\Log;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class Logger {

private $em, $token;
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, TokenStorage $token) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->token_storage = $token;
}

public function persist($r) {

    $log = new Log();
    $log->setAjax($r->isXmlHttpRequest());
    $log->setIp($r->getClientIp());
    $log->setMethod($r->getMethod());
    $log->setPath($path);
    $log->setUrl($r->getUri());

    if ($this->token_storage->getToken()) {
        $user = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof \AppBundle\Entity\User) {
            $log->setUser($user);
        }
    }

    $this->em->persist($log);
    $this->em->flush();
}

}
```

and the KernelListener.php

```
 namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use AppBundle\Service\Logger;

class KernelListener {

protected $logger;

public function __construct(Logger $logger) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {

}

public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
}

 public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
    $r = $event->getRequest();
    $this->logger->persist($r);
}

public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event) {        
}
}
```

If I remove the flush() no error is thrown, but no Log in the DB logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error **EntityManager is closed** appears because there were some database-level exceptions. So, logic of entity manager is following: if there was an exception, `EntityManager` switches to "closed" state and you can't use it anymore.

If you want to use an `EntityManager` - you need to create a new one. For example, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19077050/6699227:

```
if (!$this->entityManager->isOpen()) {
    $this->entityManager = $this->entityManager->create(
        $this->entityManager->getConnection(),
        $this->entityManager->getConfiguration()
    );
}
```

Another solution for your case could be to [create another entity manager](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html), just for writing logs. It will not be used by application itself, so it will never be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maksym was right. Thanks! In fact I used some months ago, this technique for a Service logging errors, but memory is weak specially when you are running many tasks :-(

So my working Logger is :

```
    public function persist($r) {
    if (!$this->em->isOpen()) {
        $this->em = $this->em->create(
                $this->em->getConnection(), $this->em->getConfiguration()
        );
    }

    $path = $r->get('_route');
    if (!$path || in_array($path, $this->paths)) {
        return null;
    }

    $log = new Log();
    $log->setAjax($r->isXmlHttpRequest());
    $log->setIp($r->getClientIp());
    $log->setMethod($r->getMethod());
    $log->setPath($path);
    $log->setUrl($r->getUri());

    if ($this->token_storage->getToken()) {
        $user = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof \AppBundle\Entity\User) {
            $user2 = $this->em->getReference('AppBundle:User', $user->getId());
            $log->setUser($user2);
        }
    }

    $this->em->persist($log);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```