# How to mark a Doctrine Entity Manager as "lazy" in Symfony 4.2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

After looking for a solution on how to reset a Doctrine Entity Manager after a duplicate key exception, I found this thread: [The entitity manager is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258591/the-entitymanager-is-closed)

One of the answers mentions the `resetManager()` method, which seems to be correct according to the documentation:
`$em = $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();`

Unfortunaly, when calling `resetManager()`, I get the following excpetion:

> Resetting a non-lazy manager service is not supported. Set the "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" service as lazy and require "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge" in your composer.json file instead.

I've installed the package but can't find a way to mark the default manager as lazy. I have tried in my `services.yaml`:

```
doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager:
    lazy: true
```

But this lead to further errors. How do I define the default entity manager as lazy without having to re-specify the manager completely? The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) for lazy services also didn't really help.

Thanks!

Comment: With a fresh install of S4.2 I confirmed that $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager(); generates the non-lazy error message.  I then did "composer require symfony/proxy-manager-bridge" and everything worked.  No changes to services.yaml at all.  "bin/console debug:container doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" confirmed the entity manager is lazy.  So roll back any changes you might have made to your services file, delete your cache just to be safe, and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tries it again and you are right. After installing I didn't actually try if it works, since thought I have to set it lazy by myself ("Set the "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" service as lazy and require[...]")

Answer (score 6):

As Cerad wrote in the comment, it is not required to do anything else beside of installing "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge". The rest will happen with Symfony magic.

Be aware that you **can not use the existing entity repositories** anymore with the new manager. So if you got your repositories injected / autowired before, you have to re-assign them by yourself with new ones from the new manager.

The **same goes for your entity objects**. If for example you still have a $parent entity object, create a new $child entity and assign the $child to the $parent in a relation, persisting and flushing will fail since the new manager finds detached objects.

I have tried to get it working with the existing objects via the [merge](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_merge) method of the manager, but ended up with other errors so I am just querying them again via the new manager now :(